# Replacing VGG by LeNet Caffe model

Tags: caffe, torch

this code works with a VGG caffe model (VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers.caffemodel).

When I tried to change the model to a LeNet caffemodel (below the prototxt file), I got the following error. 
In 6 module of nn.Sequential:
xx/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/nn/Linear.lua:66: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 594050], m2: [140450 x 500] at xx/torch/pkg/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:1293

Any suggestions? Many thanks!

===========================

## Code

```
net = loadcaffe.load(opt.cnn_proto, opt.cnn_model, opt.backend);
--for i = 1, 9 do  -- Lines removed when using LeNet
--    net:remove()
--end
print(net)

if opt.gpuid >= 0 then
    require 'cutorch'
    require 'cunn'
    cutorch.setDevice(opt.gpuid+1)
    net = net:cuda()
end
net:evaluate()

function loadim(imname)
    im = image.load(imname)
    im = image.scale(im,448,448)
    if im:size(1) == 1 then
        im2=torch.cat(im,im,1)
        im2=torch.cat(im2,im,1)
        im=im2
    elseif im:size(1) == 4 then
        im=im[{{1,3},{},{}}]
    end
    im = im * 255;
    im2 = im:clone()
    im2[{{3},{},{}}] = im[{{1},{},{}}]-123.68
    im2[{{2},{},{}}] = im[{{2},{},{}}]-116.779
    im2[{{1},{},{}}] = im[{{3},{},{}}]-103.939
    return im2
end

local image_root = opt.image_root

local file = io.open(opt.input_json, 'r')
local text = file:read()
file:close()
json_file = cjson.decode(text)

print(json_file['unique_img_train'])

local train_list={}
for i,imname in pairs(json_file['unique_img_train']) do
    table.insert(train_list, image_root .. imname)
end

local test_list={}
for i,imname in pairs(json_file['unique_img_test']) do
    table.insert(test_list, image_root .. imname)
end

local batch_size = opt.batch_size
local sz=#train_list
local feat_train=torch.FloatTensor(sz, 14, 14, 512)
print(string.format('processing %d images...',sz))
for i = 1, sz, batch_size do
    xlua.progress(i, sz)
    r = math.min(sz, i+batch_size-1)
    ims = torch.DoubleTensor(r-i+1, 3, 448,448)
    for j = 1, r-i+1 do
        ims[j] = loadim(train_list[i+j-1])
    end
    if opt.gpuid >= 0 then
        ims = ims:cuda()
    end
    net:forward(ims)
    feat_train[{{i,r}, {}}] = net.output:permute(1,3,4,2):contiguous():float()
    collectgarbage()
end

local train_h5_file = hdf5.open(opt.out_name_train, 'w')
train_h5_file:write('/images_train', feat_train)
train_h5_file:close()

print('DataLoader loading h5 file: ', 'data_train')
local sz = #test_list
local feat_test = torch.FloatTensor(sz, 14, 14, 512)
print(string.format('processing %d images...',sz))
for i = 1, sz, batch_size do
    xlua.progress(i, sz)
    r = math.min(sz, i + batch_size-1)
    ims = torch.DoubleTensor(r-i+1, 3, 448, 448)
    for j = 1, r-i+1 do
        ims[j] = loadim(test_list[i+j-1])
    end
    if opt.gpuid >= 0 then
        ims = ims:cuda()
    end
    net:forward(ims)
    feat_test[{{i,r}, {}}] = net.output:permute(1,3,4,2):contiguous():float()
    collectgarbage()
end

local test_h5_file = hdf5.open(opt.out_name_test, 'w')
test_h5_file:write('/images_test', feat_test)
test_h5_file:close()
```

========================

## LeNet-deploy.prototxt

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 224
  dim: 224
}
layer {
  name: "scale"
  type: "Power"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "scaled"
  power_param {
    scale: 0.0125000001863
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "scaled"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 5
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "softmax"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "softmax"
}
```